# How to add a webpage in a TabPanel in gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

I am not understanding how to add a webpage inside the tabbed panel so that when I select a tab the webpage should display in there. I am trying to use UiBinder in GWT.
I have 3 pages Page1.java, Page2.java and Page2.ui.xml.
Page1.java contains a TabPanel with 3 tab indexes, so on the index(0) of the tabPanel I want Page2.java to be displayed. 
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just `add` widgets to the `TabPanel` in order of the tabs. So if you want to have the widget from Page2.java (which I am assuming is a `Composite` widget) to be displayed in the `TabPanel` with, say, a tab text of "Page 2" you would do the following (in Page1.java):

```
TabPanel panel = new TabPanel();
panel.add(new Page2(), "Page 2");
```

For more details and examples I recommend you [read the documentation on the TabPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html).

It's also worth mentioning from the documentation:

```
This widget will only work in quirks mode. If your application is in Standards Mode, use TabLayoutPanel instead.
```

So if your host page declaration looks like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>` which means you are in *Standards Mode*, you should be using the [TabLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html) widget.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ui Binder, you could do it like this:

```
<g:TabPanel>
    <g:Tab text="Page 2">
        <app:Page2 />
    </g:Tab>
    <g:Tab text="Page 3">
        <app:Page3 />
    </g:Tab>
</g:TabPanel>
```

Inside the tab panel you can place as many tabs as you want. Inside the tab you can place a widget, composite or some panel.

The `<app:xxx>` tag you define in the `<ui:UiBinder>` tag at the top of the `zzz.ui.xml` and could look like this: `xmlns:app="urn:import:com.yourproject.package"`. So every class which lies in this package (and extends Composite (or similar)) can be used in the ui binder this way.

Also see the GWT documentation of the Ui Binder: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/2.2/DevGuideUiBinder.html